# Android Download manager limitation

Tags: android, zip, download

I need to download a file in android that is zip formatted like in he given URL so 
please suggest how ti download it via android

https://flyppdeveloper.com/downloadableFiles/FlyppIconGuidelines.zip

Answer (score 0):

```
if (enqueue == 0) {
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://o-o.preferred.del01s04.v7.nonxt1.c.bigcache.googleapis.com/androiddevelopers/shareables/icon_templates-v2.0.zip?ms=nxu&mt=1342508167&cms_redirect=yes&redirect_counter=1"));
        **request.setMimeType("application/zip");**
        enqueue = mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

just need to declare the MIME type that I was missing and therefore it was downloading arbitrary html